# Adding rows 1 by 1 to bound datatable ends up copying information from previous row

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a bound DataTable:

```
With DS
    .Tables.Add(New DataTable With {.TableName = "Changes"})
End With


Using iConn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
    Using iDA As New OleDbDataAdapter(iSelectString, Conn)
        iDA.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
        iDA.FillSchema(DS.Tables("Changes"), SchemaType.Source)
        iDA.Fill(DS.Tables("Changes"))
        iBS.DataSource = DS.Tables("Changes")
        DGVDV = DS.Tables("Changes").DefaultView

        With DataGridView1
            .DataSource = iBS
        End With
    End Using
End Using
```

And some textboxes that are bound as well:

```
dtpDate.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "HireDate")
txtEmpID.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "EmployeeID")
txtField1.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "Field1")
txtField2.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "Field2")
txtField3.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "Field3")
txtField4.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "Field4")
txtEmail.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "EmailAddresses")
txtNotes.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "OtherNotes")
txtCorrespondence.DataBindings.Add("Text", iBS, "Correspondence")
```

All of this is working beautifully so far. The issue is when I try to add new rows.

I have a Form2 with several textboxes that correspond with the columns in my DataTable, that I am bringing over in this sub:

```
Private Sub frm2_SimulateForm1ButtonClick() Handles AddingNew.SimulateForm1ButtonClick
    Form2.Hide()      
    Dim drNewRow As DataRow
    drNewRow = DS.Tables("Changes").NewRow
    drNewRow.Item("HireDate") = AddingNew.TransitionDate.ToShortDateString()
    drNewRow.Item("EmployeeID") = AddingNew.EmpID
    drNewRow.Item("Field1") = AddingNew.Field1
    drNewRow.Item("Field2") = AddingNew.Field2
    drNewRow.Item("Field3") = AddingNew.Field3
    drNewRow.Item("Field4") = AddingNew.Field4
    drNewRow.Item("EmailAddresses") = AddingNew.Email
    drNewRow.Item("OtherNotes") = AddingNew.Notes
    drNewRow.Item("Correspondence") = AddingNew.Correspondence
    drNewRow.Item("Status") = "Scheduled"
    DS.Tables("Changes").Rows.Add(drNewRow)
    DS.Tables("Changes").AcceptChanges()
End Sub
```

This works great the first time. But for every OTHER time, the OtherNotes and Correspondence fields are copied from the previous row. Can anyone advise?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Try cleaning and rebuilding your solution.

Comment: Done - issue persists. Every other field is added perfectly, except Correspondence and Notes.

Comment: Oh jesus. I think I got it. I just had to iBS.EndEdit() before showing Form2.

Comment: If you have your answer, please close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to .EndEdit() and everything is now working.